# Как определить с какой страны зашел человек?

Tags: javascript

как определить с какой странный зашел человек, Россия или Украина, Либо совсем другая

Comment: А можно узнать из какого города?

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат, можно, но особенно весело, когда мой же провайдер его не угадывает :D

Answer (score 3):

Если на JavaScript, то вот например:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback:"geoip",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("IP: "+data.ip);
    console.log("Country: "+data.country);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```